# Bing map tapped event windows phone 8.1 does not capture

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to add tapped event for Bing map in Windows Phone 8.1 to get the position at that tapped location but unfortunately, I am unable to capture that event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MapTapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en--s/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.maptapped.aspx) event instead. Then you can get location from `MapInputEventArgs` object.

XAML

```
<Maps:MapControl MapTapped="MapControl_MapTapped" />
```

C#

```
private void MapControl_MapTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
{
    Geopoint location = args.Location;
}
```